# Zend Framewrok 2: How to write custom query using tablegateway

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I need to write a update query in a model which use tablegateway. The update query sql like following.

```
UPDATE `config_settings` SET `CS_value` = CASE `CS_option`
    WHEN 'CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH' THEN '$data->CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'CATEGORY_BANNER_MAX_WIDTH' THEN '$data->CATEGORY_BANNER_MAX_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MIN_WIDTH' THEN '$data->CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MIN_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MAX_WIDTH' THEN '$data->CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MAX_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'PRODUCT_LARGE_IMAGE_WIDTH' THEN '$data->PRODUCT_LARGE_IMAGE_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'PRODUCT_MEDIUM_IMAGE_WIDTH' THEN '$data->PRODUCT_MEDIUM_IMAGE_WIDTH'
    WHEN 'PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH' THEN '$data->PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH'
    ELSE `CS_value`
END;
```

I have no idea how to implement this. The update method of tablegateway only take array of table field name and its value. So how to write this query.

I know that i can execute this query using db adapter raw sql query but i don't want this. Beside this, some times we need to some custom query in select method of tablegateway. But i found no stable way in  tablegateway.

For example:

```
select sum(CASE WHEN answers.type = 'his' THEN 1 ELSE 3 END) AS totalScore  
FROM users_questions_answers join answers on cast(answers.id as int(8))= 
users_questions_answers.answer_id group by users_questions_answers.user_id
```

How can i proceed in this situation. Any zend 2 expert suggestion will highly appreciated.
Thanks for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$this->tablegateway->update(array('CS_value' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('CASE CS_option
    WHEN "CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "CATEGORY_BANNER_MAX_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MIN_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MAX_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "PRODUCT_LARGE_IMAGE_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "PRODUCT_MEDIUM_IMAGE_WIDTH" THEN ?
    WHEN "PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH" THEN ?
    ELSE CS_value END', 
    array($data->CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH, $data->CATEGORY_BANNER_MAX_WIDTH, $data->CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MIN_WIDTH, $data->CATEGORY_PROMOTION_MAX_WIDTH, $data->PRODUCT_LARGE_IMAGE_WIDTH, $data->PRODUCT_MEDIUM_IMAGE_WIDTH, $data->PRODUCT_SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH))));
```

If `CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH` like used in the query are some constants then just remove the `double quotes` around it.

I have tried a similar query to the above one and it works just fine.

Comment: Tried to without double quote. But giving following error.  Unknown column 'CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH' in 'field list. That means update query indicate CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH as table field. For your information, CATEGORY_BANNER_MIN_WIDTH is field value.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. What error do you get when you run the query with double quotes in place? Eg: some field error OR no error with no update. Thing is that I executed a similar query in `AlbumTable` to update the `title` when the `artist` name is `SOME_NAME` and it worked, so I am a little curious about your query.